# Copy error or information messages (as text)

Tags: 18.04, gnome, shortcut-keys

In Windows when an error or information box pops up, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> (usually) copies the message into memory. Now you can paste the message into a text file, email, etc using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.

Very useful when the error is complex or long and you need to report it on sites like StackOverflow!

Is there a similar feature on Ubuntu 18.04 using GNOME? <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> does nothing and there is no right-click context menu with a helpful "Copy as text" option.

Here's an example of the sort of message it would be handy to copy/paste:

[image]

Comment: No idea on the copying error message but XSPF files are playlist files in XML format. An application like VLC will easily open that file and play the songs defined there.

Comment: @Parto: Unfortunately not relevant. I temporarily renamed the `XSPF` file to generate the displayed error as an example for this question. I've now renamed the `XSPF` file back to correct name and VLC was playing the file when I spotted your comment... :o)

Answer (score 1):

You can take a screenshot of the message and convert it to text.
Here is an example of
[a site](https://www.online-convert.com/ocr/image-to-text)
that does such a conversion.

Comment: Using a 3rd party tool is cumbersome, but that is a handy feature.

Answer (score -1):

Also in Linux you can copy such text. You can select the text with the mouse and then right click to copy. Or you can right-click the text, then select "Select all" then right-click copy. With the keyboard, provided the dialog is in focus, you can select the text with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> then copy it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>). You may first need to focus from different elements to the text using the arrow keys or tab. You will see a text cursor if the text is in focus.

Comment: This does not work. The text is not selectable and there is no right-click context menu. Ctrl+A or Ctrl+C do nothing.